# connecting to sql server from access for multiple users

Tags: microsoft-access, sql-server

I just ran the upsizing wizard on my copy of Access and have successfully connected my Access app to my SQL Server DB but I need to do this for multiple users. Am I going to have to run the upsize wizard on each machine?

I noticed that the wizard created a data source name (.dsn) file, can I use that file on the other instances of Access to connect their apps to the SQL Server DB?

Answer (score 0):

For Small Network

Front End (on every user's machine):

- Access file in ADP Format. (It contains forms and reports)

  - Copy to C: Drive (Not on the share/network drive).
- DSN File. So Access client knows where to look for SQL Servers.

Back-end

- 1 SQL Server (tables, views, stored procedures)

Comment: Ah cool, I mean, I could also put both the ADP file and the DSN on a shared drive couldnt I?

Comment: Yes, you can. For my project, I write a batch file to copy from share to local. You can run on the share using Run-time only option. However, I think local copy is better performance (run faster).